# Next Js - App crashes everywhere on set state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

My app was working fine. But after two weeks, I run it to development. The strange thing that happens is that the browser freezes when changing states. And no error is displayed.

This problem occurs in all projects And it's not just a component problem. I even tested this problem with a simple component on the main page of the project.

simple component:

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function TestComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string>("one");

  return (
    <div>
      {data}
      <button onClick={(e) => setData("two")}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when clicking, the browser freezes.

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["next", "prettier"]
}
```

`next.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --experimental-https -p 369",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@types/fbemitter": "^2.0.35",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "fbemitter": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.0",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^14.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "daisyui": "^4.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

Node version: `v19.8.1`

NPM version : `9.5.1`

- The problem is not with the browser, I tested with several browsers.
- I deleted the `node-module` and `npm cache` and reinstall it.
- I deleted the `.next` folder.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help find your problem. Please [edit] your question with a [mre].

Comment: What do you think is the problem? nextjs? if yes, try to create a new nextjs project a side and paste the code you've pasted above